# How to make a select distinct count where with CASE WHEN or IF?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot

I hope and everyone is well, I have a weekly count, where I have the id_txn, payment method and the way to pay, but I have an exception and that is that when I have a specific scenario, I want it to be added to the other payment method.

fields

```
| id_txn | way_pay | payment_meth |
  123435 | gateway | transfer    
  433564 | on-site | cash
  354641 | gateway | cash 
  124553 | paypal  | transfer
```

I want that when way_pay = gateway and payment_meth = transfer, the count is added to paypal / transfer

My query

```
select distinct way_pay, payment_meth,
  count(id_txn) as ttl_pays
from 
  pays
where 
  trunc(init_date) between trunc(to_date('date'))
case 
  when way_pay = 'gateway' and payment_meth = 'transfer' 
  then + pay_pal/transfer

group by way_pay, payment_meth;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below case statement will return 'paypay' when the `way_pay` is 'gateway' or 'paypal', and the `payment_meth` is 'transfer', otherwise it will return `way_pay`. The group by will also need the same statement.

If you want a count of distinct txn_id, then the `distinct` should be moved into the count function.

```
select 
  case when way_pay in ('gateway','paypal') and payment_meth = 'transfer' then 'paypal' else way_pay end way_pay,
  payment_meth,
  count(distinct id_txn) as ttl_pays
from 
  pays
where
  init_date between trunc(sysdate-7) and trunc(sysdate)
group by
  case when way_pay in ('gateway','paypal') and payment_meth = 'transfer' then 'paypal' else way_pay end,
  payment_meth
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the rows where count is 0 otherwise you can use below query.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b1cd5/31)

```
select DISTINCT x.way_pay, x.payment_meth, count(ID_TXN)
from (
select   payment_meth, id_txn,
  case when way_pay in ('gateway', 'paypal') and payment_meth = 'transfer' then 'paypal'
      else way_pay end as way_pay
from 
  transaction ) x
group by x.way_pay, x.payment_meth;
```